# Automatically create full backups every 7 days

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have a postgresql database configured with pgbackrest for backups. It retains full backups for 7 days:

```
[global]
repo1-retention-full-type=time
repo1-retention-full=7
```

I've set up cron to create a full backup on Sunday with incremental backups each day. This works as expected and removes full backups after the most recent is >7 days old. The actual crontab calls a script that uses the pgbackrest commands, but for simplicity:

```
0 0 * * 0   root    pgbackrest --type=full backup
0 0 * * 1-6 root    pgbackrest backup
```

I'm looking to configure pgbackrest up to automatically create full backups every 7 days so I would only need one cron job:

```
0 0 * * *   root    pgbackrest backup
```

Is this possible, or will I have to write some bash logic in my script?

Comment: why not use a cron job for this

Comment: @nbk already explained in the question body, it's only 7 sentences long